# Word order in a which clause with the phrase "there are"

Tags: word-order

If sb. told us which kinds of duck exist in this are, should we rather say that "he told us which kinds of duck there are", or that "he told us which kinds of duck are there"? Sorry to bother you for this silly question, but for some reason I find it too confusing to decide....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Word order in an embedded question ("She can't decide which IS the best place for it")](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/280799/word-order-in-an-embedded-question-she-cant-decide-which-is-the-best-place-fo) Also [Where does the verb go on this question? Is it even a reported question?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93371/) and [“I'm not sure what the right way is”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51123/), among others

Comment: _There are_ denotes existence/presence, but without reference to any particular place. To refer explicitly to the area in question, _there_ needs to come after _are_. You could even say _there are there_ to denote existence/presence in that particular place.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/608581/2085).